# Redirection in Linux

Tags: c, linux, input, io-redirection

Input files to test project 2. Intended to be used via redirection.

My professor gave us a txt file to use to test if our program works. It reads in ~1000 numbers (so we wouldn't have to manually enter them). But I don't know the linux command on how to use this txt file.

```
ccarri7@ubuntu:~/C$ ls
ccarri7lab2  ccarri7lab2.c  lab2input.txt
ccarri7@ubuntu:~/C$
```

This is the folder where my executable/source/txt file are.

Comment: To redirect stdin: `./your_prog < lab2input.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./ccarri7lab2 < lab2input.txt
```

will use the text in lab2input.txt as arguments for ccarri7lab2

http://linux.about.com/od/itl_guide/a/gdeitl42t01.htm

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
ccarri7lab2 < lab2input.txt
```

Hope this is what you want, else you can give some more info.

Comment: That's just going to overwrite the input file.

Comment: @CarlNorum: you seem to be confused with *output* redirection, `ccarri7lab2 > lab2input.txt`.

Comment: Answerer changed the direction of the `<` since I wrote that comment.

Comment: Yes @CarlNorum In hurrily I typed opposite way